# Visual Studio closes immediately because evaluation expired - how to enter key

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, update 3 (version 14.0.25420.1). It used to be activated using my MSDN license bound to my Microsoft account, and that worked. However, recently Visual Studio started closing immediately after I open it, without any explanation.

I've tried to install [Cumulative Servicing Release for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (KB3165756)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx) which is supposed to be version 10.25431.1, but it just did a repair, and didn't change anything. `devenv /safemode` does the same.

To debug, I ran `devenv /log my.log`, and the log shows this:

```
<type>Warning</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>The evaluation period has expired. The application will be shutdown.</description>
```

[How to Unlock Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn950037.aspx) discusses where to enter product keys or try to re-activate, but I can't get to the UI at all! How can I recover my Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the exact same issue after upgrading from VS 2015 Pro Update 2 to VS 2015 Pro Update 3.

Numerous repairs, uninstall, reinstall would not fix the issue.

I finally reinstalled VS 2015 Pro Base (Without Updates) and my previous MSDN credentials were used to automatically sign in.

Unfortunately, when I reapplied Update 3, the issue returned.

Not a complete answer, but hopefully it might be helpful.